# Excess Baggage Costs

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, turkish-airlines

I expect to travel with Turkish Airline from London Gatwick to Dar es Salaam, Tanzania via Istanbul. 
The baggage allowance is 30kg including the carry-on suitcase. Is there anyone who knows how much it will cost to have an extra suitcase that weighs 30kg or less?

I emailed their London office a couple of times but no one has replied yet.

Comment: Hi, have you checked this website https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-tr/any-questions/excess-baggage/index.html, and does it contain the information you need? If not, you may have to edit the question and clarify your specific need, and how it is not addressed in the help page.

Comment: The help page allows customers to calculate costs based on regions and piece regions. Unfortunately, my departure airport and destination airport do not occure on the mentioned piece regions (i.e Piece region 1 and Piece region 2

Answer (score 2):

Turkish Airlines operates [two different baggage charging policies](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-es/any-questions/free-baggage/index.html) depending on where your flight is from/to - a kilo concept and a piece concept.

The free baggage allowance, and hence excess baggage charge is calculated under the piece concept only if you fly from/to the following places:

> The baggage piece concept applies to flights to and from Angola, Argentina, Benin , Burkina Faso, Cameroon, Canada, Chad, Colombia, Cuba, Democratic Republic of Congo, Gabon, Ghana, Guinea, Ivory Coast, Japan, Madagascar, Mali, Mauritania, Mauritius, Niger, Nigeria, Panama, Senegal, the Seychelles, Sierra Leone, South America, Sudan, the United States of America, and Venezuela.

Since neither your origin or destination fall into this list, the kilo (weight) concept applies.

[This page](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-tr/any-questions/excess-baggage/index.html) details the excess baggage charges:

- Your departure airport London is in region 4 and the destination airport Dar es Salaam is in region 5 (see table 1).
- The charge for 1kg excess baggage between regions 4 and 5 is €27 (see table 2).

So if all your luggage together weighs e.g. 55kg (the number of pieces is not relevant) and the allowance is 30kg, you will pay €675 for 25kg excess baggage.

Comment: After more digging on Turkish Airline's website, I start to see where the confusion comes from - the OP may be believing that his baggage allowance is under the piece concept, whereas it is _likely_ that the excess baggage fee for his flight is calculated under the weight concept instead. I will do an edit - hope you don't mind.

Comment: @B.Liu You are right. I have approved your edit.